# How to see Erlang application Console which is running in backgroud?

Tags: erlang, rebar

I am using rebar for release build of erlang application, when I use start option to start the application it is running fine in background and It returns me the command prompt. I don't want to see all the background output, so I did not run using console option.  But If I need any time what is going in background, to check the console due to any error, how do I get that running application's console?

Answer (score 2):

I guess that you have made a release using Rebar and that you have started the node with the generated start script.

So the best way would be to use the start option 'attach':

```
./bin/mynode attach
```

It will connect to the shell through pipes so you will be in the actual node that are running so be careful with using Ctrl-c. (add the option "+Bi" to your vm.args file to restrict that..)

Answer (score 1):

You can connect a remote shell to the node, provided it's been set up for distribution. Use the following command:

```
erl -sname rem -remsh node@host -setcookie the_cookie -hidden
```

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl-G to enter JCL mode, then 'j' to list, then 'c' followed by a number to connect to the chosen job.  See the [eshell docs](http://erlang.org/doc/man/shell.html), specifically the JCL section.

Oh, or if by 'command prompt' you mean an OS shell rather than an Erlang shell, IIRC you need to start an Erlang node that is appropriately -name'd or -sname'd (whichever the node you want to connect to uses), then connect to that node ('r' in JCL mode), then connect to the job.